# Why am I getting a line shadow in a seaborn line plot?

Tags: python, seaborn, confidence-interval

Here is the code:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(14,8))
sns.lineplot(x='season', y='team_strikerate', hue='batting_team', data=overall_batseason)
plt.legend(title = 'Teams', loc = 1, fontsize = 12)
plt.xlim([2008,2022])
```

And here is the image
[image]

Just to let you know, I've already drawn another similar lineplot above this one.

Comment: The "shadow" isn't a shadow but a confidence interval. Use `ci=None` to leave it out. https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is line shadow showing the confidence interval, because the dataset contains **multiple y**(*team_strikerate*) values **for each x**(*season*) value. By default, [`sns.lineplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) will estimate the **mean** by **aggregating** over multiple y values at each x value.

After aggregation, the **mean of y** values at each x value will be plotted as a **line**. The **line shadow** represents the **95% confidence interval** of the estimate.

---

To remove the line shadow, you can pass the argument `ci=None` to `sns.lineplot()`.
(credit to @JohanC for providing this idea in this question's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62897548/why-am-i-getting-a-line-shadow-in-a-seaborn-line-plot#comment111227283_62897548))

To change the confidence interval, you can pass the argument `errorbar=('ci', <int>)` to `sns.lineplot()`.

Answer (score 1):

The semi transparent region around the line is the confidence interval. You can remove the confidence interval by setting the ci parameter of the lineplot() function to None. refer this link for more info://wellsr.com/python/seaborn-line-plot-data-visualization/